# Take partial derivative of squared dot product

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I want to take the partial derivative of $ z = (y⋅x)^2$ with respect to $x$, where $y$, $x$ are vectors. Should I be correct to assume that we can see this as $ z = g(x)^2$, where $g(x) = (y⋅x)$. So using chain rule

\begin{align} ∂z/∂x &= ∂z/∂g * ∂g/∂x, \\
    ∂z/∂x &= 2(y⋅x)y. \end{align}

I'm probably butchering the notation though.

Comment: If you define $p_y(x) = (x \mid y)$ ("dot product by $y$") and $\varphi(t) = t^2,$ you want to differentiate $f=\varphi \circ p_y;$ the chain rule gives at once $f'(x)=2 p_y(x) p_y'(x) = 2 (x \mid y) p_y.$ When we identify $p_y$ canonically with a vector, we have $p_y = y,$ hence the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. Recall that the dot product is defined by $y \cdot x = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i x_i$, so $(y \cdot x)^2 = (\sum_i y_i x_i)^2$. Now you want to calculate $\partial z / \partial x$, which is the gradient $(\partial z/\partial x_1, \dots , \partial z /\partial x_n)$. By the chain rule,

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_i} = 2y_i \left (\sum_i x_i y_i \right)$$

for all $i$, hence

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 2 (x \cdot y) y.$$

Comment: Thanks! So the notation $∂z/∂x=∂z/∂g∗∂g/∂x$ is correct right?

Comment: Yes, this is correctly written.